# Random double generation between a range in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to generate random doubles between a range

The `nextint()` function takes a param max where as the `nextdouble()` doesnt take any params.
Is there any other methods that return random doubles between a range in dart?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't, but it easy to recreate it since `nextInt` takes only a `max` value (exclusive).

`nextDouble() * max`

Answer (score 26):

The `nextDouble` returns a value between 0 and 1 (not included). So, if you want a number in the range `a` (included) to `b` (not included), you can just do:

```dart
double doubleInRange(Random source, num start, num end) => 
    source.nextDouble() * (end - start) + start;

print(doubleInRange(random, a, b));
```

Comment: Why not use `double` instead of `int` for parameters?

`double doubleInRange(Random source, double start, double end) => 
    source.nextDouble() * (end - start) + start;`

Comment: The code above can be represented in the following mathematical notation: [0,1) => [0, max-min) => [min, max)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is. If you want just double values you can convert the integer value to double

```dart
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  var rng = new Random();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print(rng.nextInt(100).toDouble());
  }
}
```

If you want the type of double values generated by nextDouble() such as '0.2502033576383784' i suggest you create a function to handle the range of values.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

main() {
  var rng = new Random();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print(rng.nextDouble() + rng.nextInt(50));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one more simple solution to add to the list(only with Max range).

```
var random = Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(45);
double randTemp = random.nextDouble() * randomInt;
```

Comment: This will _not_ give you a random number uniformly distributed between 0 and 45. You'll be much more likely to get a low number than a high number.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer can't generate negative numbers, top scored answer can be better with extension functions.
write this function in any class of your app:

```
extension RX on Random {
  double randomDouble(double min, double max) {
    return (nextDouble() * (max - min) + min);
  }
}
```

and use it simple: `random.randomDouble(-5, 5)`